# WiFi only connects to my router, not to any other access point

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi, openelec

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with a WiFi USB dongle. I don't know the brand or model, I got it for free with my Xtreamer Mk1 in 2009. My Windows 7 PC installs some generic Realtek RTL8191SU WLAN adapter driver when I plug it in. On the Pi I use OpenELEC 5.0.5 which also has drivers for it.

**My network setup**

In my living room on the first floor, I have an [AVM Fritz!Box 6360 Cable](http://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-6360-cable/technical-data/) router (802.11bgna). In my office on the third floor, I have an additional access point ([Linksys WRT54GL](http://www.linksys.com/en-eu/products/routers/WRT54GL) (802.11bg only), but I also tried a [TP-Link TL-WA901ND](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=239&model=TL-WA901ND)). The Fritz!Box provides a main network and a guest network, both with letter-only SSIDs and secured with WPA2 Personal. The main network's passphrase looks like `Hello123+World456=Foobar789` (alphanumeric, plus and equal signs), the guest network's passphrase is all lower-case letters. The access point in the office only provides the main network on a different channel (5 channels distance to the Fritz!Box, channels 3 and 8), with the same security settings, of course. We use the main network mainly with our iPad 2 and our mobile phones (Sony Xperia Z2, Google Nexus 5) which have no problems whatsoever including seemless roaming between the two stations.

**My problem**

As soon as it works, the Pi is going to be a media player in a room where I can't put an ethernet cable. And since those powerline things have a *really* bad transmission rate in my case, I chose WiFi. The Pi detects the USB dongle and the OpenELEC setup UI also shows me some networks, including my main and guest networks. When I connect to my main network, the status always becomes *associating* and then *failure*. Since OpenELEC uses *connman* to manage its connections, I looked into *connman*'s config files (via SSH and a wired connection). It says `Failure=invalid-key` on the last line. But I checked it about 20 times now - the key was correct. When I tried to connect to my guest network, it instantly worked. First I thought it was the passphrase. (Maybe the main network's passphrase was saved incorrectly or something.) I even tried changing the main network's passphrase multiple times. But I found out that the problem was the access point. When I plugged out the AP, the Pi connected to my main network without any problems. Then I thought that the USB dongle may be incompatible with the access point and tried another access point (the TP-Link mentioned above), but the problem was still there. Then I plugged the USB dongle into my Windows PC, and my PC had no problems connecting to the access point (the Linksys again, I had the TP-Link just for a short time).

So apparently, it's just the Pi that won't connect to any of my access points, but perfectly connects to my router. Does anyone have a hint for me how to solve this? Or at least a suggestion what I haven't tried yet? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: If you need more information, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the wireless dongle in your Pi. It **is** a very basic dongle that comes with it, so try a different dongle and hopefully that should solve the problem.

Kind Regards,

Indraj Gandham